# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter share plugin version ^0.6.5+2 with firebase dynamic link. The plugin works fine when run in debug mode but when I create release apk using

```
flutter build apk --release
```

or flutter run --release, the share plugin gives error

```
E/flutter (17160): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share 
on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
E/flutter (17160): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159)
E/flutter (17160): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17160): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17160):
```

I have tried running Flutter clean and then build or run  again but still it gives the same error